# Kernel restart - when fitting model

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a 10GB root file with 30 columns and 60 million rows.
I got an error when I tried to import all data at once in pandas dataframe. I managed it by reading it in chunks, performing some pre selection cut, and managing data types.

After all that, I am finished with 2GB dataframe.
But still, when I tried to fit data to let’s say logistic regression or Random Forest, my kernel keeps dying/restarting.
Any solution?

Comment: What are you using for the ML models?

Comment: If I understood your question, I am using jupyter notebook with 16GB of RAM